# Ignore some rows while aggregating based on a condition

Tags: sql

I have a table like below

```
Class   Type   Value
-------------------------
C1       A       1
C1       B       2
C1       C       7
C2       B       8
C2       C       2
C3       C       3
```

I need to get result set with below condition

**If type A is present in a Class then pick value corresponding to it ignoring other types, but if it not there then take an average of all the types present**

The result should be like

```
    Class   Value
   ------------------
     C1       1                   
     C2       5            
     C3       3
```

Note: Please avoid using inline queries (Sub Queries) in solution as it will increase execution time.

I have already tried below query:

```
Select Class, AVG(Value) 
From A 
WHERE (Type='A' OR 0=(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM A WHERE Type='A'))
GROUP BY Class
```

Comment: "avoid using inline queries" -- probably the professor is talking about correlated queries.

Comment: َPlease don't tag multiple DBMSs, pick only the one which you are using.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: No beacuse i have already done using inline query in where clause but it is taking some seconds to execute. By the way i am a graduate and a working professional. :)

Comment: @mtr.web  I have edited my question. Thanks !!

Comment: Do you mean subqueries?

Comment: Yes @Avin Kavish.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `coalesce()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select class,
       coalesce(max(case when type = 'A' then value end),
                avg(value)
               ) as new_value
from t
group by class;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. I got a new perspective to approach these kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You  could  try using an union between the two set of data

```
select class, value 
from my_table  m 
inner join (
  select distinct class
  from my_table  
  where type  ='A'
) t on m.class = t.class and m.type='A'
union 
select  class, avg(value)
from my_table m 
inner join (
  select distinct class 
  from my_table  
  where class not in  (
    select distinct class
    from my_table  
    where type  ='A'
  )
) t on t.class = m.class 
group by class
```